# Swift: model structs, using optionals vs initialization of empty values

Tags: ios, swift, var, null

In `Swift`, say for example I have a `struct` for this `model`:

```
struct Message {
    var message: String = ""
    var timestamp: String = ""
    var id: String = ""
}
```

And I would be instantiating multiple `Messages` using this `struct` from a database, and then populate a `TableView` with them.

Would it be best practice to using optionals instead of setting these variables with empty strings like such?

```
struct Message {
    var message: String?
    var timestamp: String?
    var id: String?
}
```

**Would it be more efficient to basically setting the variables to `nil` vs an `empty string`? Does `nil` take less memory vs `empty string`?**

Comment: highly recommend to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288488/when-should-i-use-optionals-and-when-should-i-use-non-optionals-with-default-val) question. The answer there gives a good explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before thinking about optimization, you have to ask yourself the good question: is there any chance that `Message` may contain optionals for one or several of its properties? If yes, use optionals, if no, don't use optionals.

Then, if you want to improve your code, you can use *memberwise initializer* for your `struct`:

```
struct Message {
    var message: String
    var timestamp: String?
    var id: String
}

let message = Message(message: "Some message", timestamp: nil, id: "Id14")
```

Finally, I doubt any memory optimization on `Struct` (with optional or non optional properties) will give any significant improvement to your app/project.

Comment: Good question to ask myself. In my case, I would say no chance for `nil` since they will be coming from a database. And I would rather leave empty/default values instead of `null` in my db. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -6):

Avoid optionals whenever it is possible. Stored properties are not as magical as they are in objective-c. Just give them default values if it is appropriate.

Comment: `optionals` gives you a lot of flexibility in many cases. There is no need to initialize dummy empty strings without necessity.

Comment: And they also complicates logic.